# Update/Change all ID in PhpMyAdmin (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a problem with a Joomla migration (Kunena forum component)
When I try to copy the old forum table to the new one, I receive "Duplicate error" message.

A simple solution must be to change all the values in the ID column.

The table now:

```
id |   name

1  | Foo

2  | Bar
```

etc...

Can I add the numbers "20" for every rows? So the result will be:

```
id  |   name

201 | Foo

202 | Bar
```

etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `id` = CONCAT('20', `id`);
```